# Telegram Bot API Deep Linking to validate newly registered users: Wrong or not?

Tags: web-services, api-design, telegram, telegram-bot, spam-prevention

*Just a preface. You can skip to the next heading.*

I'm working on a startup with a limited budget. Recently, I've been trying to design a RESTful API as a backend for the mobile app i'm working on. (A Web based SPA client is going to be developed in near future too). Of course it's not a public API but we know it "can" get revealed by tampering network activity or investigating the Web Client source files.

Almost all of the API methods are protected using JWT-based Token Authorization EXCEPT user registration method which accepts an `email` and a `password` and creates a user. So, the system would be vulnerable to spammers.

**SMS as the best solution**

*You can skip to the next heading.*

I've been investigating various approaches like IP rate limiting and CAPTCHA on mobile app (!) to block spammers but none of them were satisfying. So I came to the idea of E-mail verification which would not be the best approach either. Spammers can easily create fake E-mail addresses and parse incoming mail contents to validate their batch of registered accounts.

The best I found out so far is to use SMS verification. Phone numbers are not easy to fake and each of them will cost for the spammer. It's not perfect but minimizes the risk. So i decided to generate and store a key in DB, send it to the user via SMS, and require them to enter the code in the app. Then, if correct, register the user and store the phone number to prevent multiple usages of the same number. So far so good.

**Telegram Bot as a replacement of SMS Verification**

As the budget is limited, i've came to the idea of using Telegram beside SMS verification to reduce the costs related to SMS Service Providers. So here is the idea.

Telegram uses the same approach. It verifies the phone number on user registration. Thus, we can rely on the fact that each Telegram user is a real person with a valid phone number. So, I can develop a Telegram bot named like **ValidatorBot**, and use [Deep Linking feature](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking) to start the bot with a parameter indicating the registration request which is going to be validated:

```
https://telegram.me/ValidatorBot?start=user_registration_token
```

And then show the link above as "**Register Using Telegram**". When the user opens the link and Clicks on START button of the bot screen, a message containing `user_registration_token` would be sent to my server, so i can mark the registration process identified  by `user_registration_token` as a valid process and continue with registering the user and store their Telegram User ID to block multiple account creations with a single Telegram account.

I haven't seen any implementations like this before and could not find anything relevant on the web about it. Here are the different aspects that I could analyze so far:

- It would not be a user friendly way to make them open Telegram, click on Start, then switch back to the app to be able to continue.
- A Telegram User can be deleted. The spammer can delete their Telegram user, create a new one using the same phone number, and register again with a new Telegram UserID. Although, it's not such a big concern because Telegram denies multiple registration intents by a specific phone number in a limited time domain for at least 24hrs. (Three registrations per day I think).

What do you think? Do you see any gaps in this verification method? Any security flaws?

Would it be better not to rely on just pressing START button and show a code to user after pressing it, and requiring them to enter the code in app? (Like how it was in SMS method) Or getting START signal is enough?

Answer (score 3):

You can request phone number by Telegram bot button and get real phone number of the user, so you can save your money for SMS price.

Comment: Well, It's good that we'll still have SMS available after that. Hopefully. :)